# Почему вложенный цикл выдаёт различные результаты когда работает с локальными переменными и глобальными?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Почему вложенный цикл выдаёт различные результаты, когда работает с (идентичными)  локальными переменными и глобальными в js?

1. Вариант

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;


for (; i < 3; ++i) {

  for (; j < 3; ++j) {
    alert(`${i},${j}`);
  }
}
```

Выдаст результаты:
1)0,0
2)0,1
3)0,2

2. Вариант

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

  for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    alert(`${i},${j}`);
  }
}
```

Выдаст результаты:
1)0,0
2)0,1
3)0,2
4)1,0
5)1,1
6)1,2
7)2,0
8)2,1
9)2,2

Comment: Неравнозначное сравнение, потому что в первом случае, вы не обнуляете **j** в начале цикла. Область видимости переменных тут не при чем. Напишите `for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)` и всё встанет на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что переменная j не обнуляется после итераций цикла с переменной i.

С помощью дебагера это несложно проверить. На этом сайте конечно дебагер не запускается, но вы можете скопировать код и попробовать у себя на проекте или даже просто в консоли.

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

debugger;
for (; i < 3; ++i) {

  for (; j < 3; ++j) {
    console.log(`${i},${j}`);
  }
}
```